# Python openpyxl - Read an Excel file and set null for blank cells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import json

wb = load_workbook(filename='Deployment Plan_2015.xlsx',read_only=True)
ws = wb['Deployment Plan']
x = 4
data = []

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
            if not cell.value:
                    print('null')
                    x = x+1
            else:
                    print(ws['A'+str(x)].value)
                    data.append(ws['A'+str(x)].value)
                    x = x+1

print(json.JSONEncoder(data).encode(data))
```

It only reads the first the first cell(there are 4 more projects after Project 1) then prints everything as null:

```
Project 1
null
null
```

It continues for a few more nulls it ends with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maynor\Documents\Python\projects\DPprojectlister.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(ws['A'+str(x)].value)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.2-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 400, in __getitem__
    return self._get_cell(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.2.2-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\iter_worksheet.py", line 168, in _get_cell
cell = tuple(self.get_squared_range(col, row, col, row))[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

It's suppose to print the data encoded in JSON after it reaches the end of the column

Comment: Well, you start at A4, then, for each row, for each cell in the row, you increment that 4. So, if the sheet is 10x10, you'll eventually be asking for A104. Which doesn't exist, because the sheet is 10x10, not 104xsomething. How did you _expect_ this to work?

Comment: show a bit of the organization of the sheet: A4 says Project 1. Are the values you want in the same row, stretching across, and if so, how far?

Comment: I only want to print values from column A but there are some  values in other columns. I only specifically want values from column A

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you should probably look at using the `get_squared_range()` method of the worksheet to get a range of cells such as A4:D10 to work with.

FWIW as the traceback shows the error is coming from looking up the value of a cell before it has been created. Use `ws.cell()` if you want to look up cells programmatically.

To get all the cells from column A:
`ws.get_squared_range(min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=ws.max_row)`

To get just some: `ws['A1':'A10']`

Comment: I'm trying to get values from only column A. Thank you for the information